# Angular7 - Call function/API when loading/changing component

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm working on a dashboard and I would like to print the amount of message there is in a mailbox on the icon of the mailbox.

I'm not sure if my idea is the best but to do this, I should probably call my API (getCountMail) everytime a component is changed/page reloaded/route changed/ ect ...

Is it the right way to do this? It really look like a bad idea to do that but I don't find any other solution ...

I tried something with Websocket but I failed.

I tried to simply add the function in the app.component.ts constructor but it call it just once.

Comment: App will be created only once thus 1 constructor call. What keeps you from creating service that will query for messages at some intervals in the background?

Comment: Wesockets should be the way to go, or you can use [RxjS's `timer` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html)

Comment: trichetriche is right, websocket is your best play here

Comment: Have you tried using FireBase (which is a realtime database) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best with a websocket to update the counter, that would allow you to have the total in real time. If you do not want to do it in real time you can always call getCountMail () every X time but it would not be in real time. Or you can also call each time you update the page.

If you decide on websocket this can help you:
https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1

Comment: Yhea i guess too :/ I'm gonna retry to implement it, but i got a lot of error when i tried to implement it. Thanks

Comment: try with websocket and if you have any problem we can always help to solve the error ;)